# trouble creating python3 -m venv py_envv using windows subsystem linux (using ubantu distribution)

Tags: command-line, apt, python, python3, virtualenv

Its my first post in askUbuntu, please bare with my discription.

command at PWD :  python3 -m venv py_envv
after excuting I got an error below

---

The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

```
apt install python3.10-venv
```

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/mnt/<>/<>////AirflowBasics/py_envv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']

can anyone able to resolve this issue , please let me know if you want more context reagrding my environment or other things.
Thanks.

Comment: yes i tried using (sudo),  and It says "Package python3.10-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source"

Comment: Edit your question to show complete, accurate input and output of what you did to install `python3-venv`. Also add the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 22.04-22.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
python3 -m venv py_env1
```

The `python3 -m venv py_env1` command will create a directory called "py_env1" in your home directory, containing everything you need to install any Python package.

To use the new Python virtual environment run the following commands:

```
cd py_env1
source ./bin/activate
```